# ServiceStack ServiceClient HTTP 206 and Range header

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack ServiceClient to write an API wrapper. The API returns HTTP 206 if the number of entities to be returned is too great. Is there a a good way to handle this with ServiceClient, for example for an API endpont that's wrapped like this:

```
var result = client.Get<IEnumerable<TResource>>("path");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) service that's returning a **HTTP 206**? as this isn't behavior that's in-built into ServiceStack. If you are using a ServiceStack you may need to increase your IIS/ASP.NET Request limits to allow larger responses.

Otherwise if you're talking to a 3rd Party API, you shouldn't use [ServiceStack's Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) which are opinionated towards consuming ServiceStack services. You should instead use something like the [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) built into ServiceStack which would allow you to specify custom HTTP Headers if your service supports it, you can ask for a Partial **Content-Range** by specifying it in a HTTP Request Filter, e.g:

```
var json = "http://example.org/users".GetJsonFromUrl(
    requestFilter: httpReq => httpReq.AddRange(0, 1000));
```

Comment: Hm, OK. It's a non-servicestack API. `JsonServiceClient` has worked perfectly until I hit this stumbling block...